# Given a random value and its expected value, how can you determine if another random variable exists?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose there exists a random variable $X$ with $E[X] = 1$, can $E[2^{-X}] = \frac{1}{4}$ exist? Can $E[2^X] = 8$ exist? Is there a general method to solve this type of problem?

Comment: @NateEldredge, care to explain please?

Comment: You may want to check Jensen's inequality, noting $2^{-t}$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality, if the expectations involved are finite, and if $f(t)$ is a convex function, we have $f(E[X]) \le E[f(X)]$.  This limits the possible values.

Now note $2^{-t}, 2^t$ are both convex, so work out the bounds implied by Jensen.